# How to upgrade Django to 2.0 version

Tags: python, django, linux, pip

I've been traying to upgrade my django versión and I've coudnt.

```
xxx@yyyyyy:~# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 11, 10, u'final', 0)

xxxx@yyyyyyy:~# pip install -U Django 
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Django)

xxxx@yyyyyy:~# pip --no-cache-dir install -U Django
Requirement already up-to-date: Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Django)
```

How it coud be up-to-date my django version if `enter code here`it is not 2.0 it is (1, 11, 10, u'final', 0)

And If I do an ls -s to know the files owners:

```
xxxx@yyyyyyy:~# ls -s /home/gechichure/.cache/pip
total 12
4 http  4 selfcheck.json  4 wheels
```

Not root or my useradmin ?!?!?! I do not understand how django it works and how pip it really works :(

I need to upgrade to 2.0 versión !!

Please any suggestions would be apprecciate.

Regards !!!

Comment: django 2.0 is only compatible with python3, so it does not support python. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/: *Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. We highly recommend and only officially support the latest release of each series.

The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7.*

Comment: Note that Django 2.0 _requires_ python 3.4+ (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/); 1.11 is the final version that supported python 2.7

Comment: Perfect answer, so the other question would be how to set  python 3.5 as a default. Becase I have installed both of them and in myproject I work with 3.5. But when y run Python on my promt by default is python2.7

Comment: execute: `xxx@yyyyyy:~#  python3` and `pip3 install  Django `

Comment: Perfect! but Im still have one more problem, the /home/myuser/.cache//pip/http and /home/myuser/.cache//pip its parent directory is not owned by the current user !!!   Im root !!! how cant it be ? thats the second part of my first questión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 2.0 isn't available for Python 2.7, so you should install Python 3 to work with it. I recommend making a virtualenv to don't have problem with the instalation.

Follow this steps and you will success :) https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000695551-Installing-and-using-Python-s-virtualenv-using-Python-3