# I am unable to upgrade from Django 1.8 to 2.0

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, pip

How can I update Django from 1.8 to 2.0.2? I am unable to doing this. I am using python 3.5

[image]

Comment: You should run `python3` because you upgraded using `pip3`

Comment: Please don’t post a screenshot. Copy and paste the error instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade to Django 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872885/how-to-upgrade-to-django-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use a virtualenv. Once you have installed Django in a virtualenv, the `django-admin` command will work once you have activated the virtualenv.

If you still want to use the Django that you installed using `pip3`, you should use the `python3` command.

```
python3
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

You can also use `python -m django` instead of `django-admin` or `django-admin.py`, to make sure that you are using the correct version of Python, for example:

```
python3 -m django --version
```